# Do MPI library need an OS for heterogeneous multicore system?

Tags: operating-system, mpi, multicore, bare-metal, heterogeneous

I am new to multicore. As a beginner my question maybe basic,my question is can MPI library be supported in **baremetal** heterogeneous systems ? or do we need an OS  (like RTOS) to support the MPI library ? It will be useful if anyone can provide links of any implemented MPI on a heterogenous system with or without OS. Anything will be useful for understanding. Thanks in advance.

EDIT : I would also like to know the general requirements of a system for MPI , if not specific.

Comment: do you have a specific hardware in mind ?

Comment: its LPC4300 from NXP

Comment: None of the existing MPI libraries that I am aware of will run on bare metal.  They all require o/s services such as process starting, inter-process comms, loading code, file access, i/o, ...

Comment: If you are targeting a single multicore host, you might give a look at OpenMP support for heterogeneous parallel execution. In any case, you will need an OS running. Maybe this requirement is not necessary for coprocessors, but that depends entirely on what hardware the library supports.

Answer (score 0):

I am not too sure what you mean with a baremetal heterogeneous system.

You need to have an operating system

We tried to perform a simulation distributed into serveral processes. Some processes were calculated on a Linux (RedHat6) and some on Windows7 machine. 
We used intel mpi. The pmi_proxy needs to be accessible on all machines.

Since the machines were connected with a normal gigabit lan connection, the performance was rather poor. MPI really benefits form a quick connection like [infiniband](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/InfiniBand).

The general requirement is that you need to have a connecting network between the machines. They even turn [several raspberry pis into a supercomputer](https://www.golem.de/news/miniplatine-64-raspberry-pi-werden-zu-einem-supercomputer-1209-94531.html) (I would perhaps say cluster).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24668811/process-manager-in-mpi) is a quite similar question.

[Problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13387356/mpiexec-hydra-how-to-run-mpi-process-on-machines-where-locations-of-hydra-pmi) like this may occur.

Comment: the system i mention here is LPC4300 series. There are two cores Cortex m4 and M0. They have no OS running. They simply communicate via the IPC . So, I wanted to try MPI in which , I do not have to deal with IPC  i.e ,by having a portable code which is possible on both the cores. Possibly a parallel programming for the heterogeneous systems.